# How do i copy a file INTO the /data/data/... directory on android?

Tags: android, linux, emulation

So I have been trying to copy a file into a specific location in the /data/data dirrectory, with no luck.

I am using this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm terminal emulator.

Whenever I try to copy the file into the directory, it says

> /system/bin/sh: can't create kbox3-install-base: Permission denied

Comment: For that you will need to root your device.

Comment: Or use run-as or have the owning app grant permission to the directory.  But without a specific need tied to software development, your question is **off topic** here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to root your device first to access these system located folders and files. No way without root permission with yours.

Comment: That is not necessarily true.  But the question is off topic anyway.